# Check type of struct in Go

Tags: go, reflection

I'm trying to check the type of a struct in Go. This was the best way I could come up with. Is there a better way to do it, preferably without initializing a struct?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Test struct{
    foo int
}

func main() {
    t := Test{5}
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(t) == reflect.TypeOf(Test{}))
}
```

Comment: What is the motivation for this? Are you able to use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Type assertions:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Test struct {
    foo int
}

func isTest(t interface{}) bool {
    switch t.(type) {
    case Test:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

func main() {
    t := Test{5}
    fmt.Println(isTest(t))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dotXc8BTcU)

---

And, more simplified:

```
_, isTest := v.(Test)
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-7-DnVF5Y76)

---

You can refer to the [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) for a technical explanation.

Comment: Why does this work, but not something like `_, ok := t.(Test)`? That gives the error `invalid type assertion: t.(Test) (non-interface type Test on left)`

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. The important bit here is not the type switch, but rather the implicit conversion to interface{} in the function argument. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You may pass a "typed" `nil` pointer value to [`reflect.TypeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf), and call `Type.Elem()` to get the type of the pointed value. This does not allocate or initialize a value of the type (in question), as only a `nil` pointer value is used:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(t) == reflect.TypeOf((*Test)(nil)).Elem())
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IdWGRxoqqQ).

P.S. This is an exact duplicate, but can't find the original.

Comment: Sorry if this is a duplicate. I couldn't find the original myself.

Comment: Looking at this, this is certainly clever, but less idiomatic IMO than what Emile provided. Thank you so much for the answer, though :)

Comment: @ollien Yes, type assertion is easier and faster, but you tagged the quesiton with [tag:reflection].

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have. I tagged it as that because everything I found regarding checking types used it. Should I remove the tag? 

FWIW, I'm not the one who downvoted you.

Comment: @ollien Don't think you should, your solution uses reflection.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply assign **t** to an empty interface variable and check its type

and you don't need to necessarily write a function to check this out.

```
var i interface{} = t
v, ok := i.(Test)
//v = concrete value of Test struct
//ok = is (t) a type of the Test struct?
```